# How to implement power iteration method for sparse matrix in python

Tags: python, iteration, sparse-matrix

I am trying to implement the power iteration method for 10 iterations using a sparse matrix to calculate the eigenvector vector after 10 iterations and its runtime.

In this case, the sparse matrix = HS and the initial page rank vector = pg_vector, where webpage_count = 10001.

```
%%time

pg_vector = np.array([1/webpage_count]*webpage_count)

for i in range(10):
    pg_vector1 = np.dot(HS, pg_vector)

    # calculate the norm
    pg_vector1_norm = np.linalg.norm(pg_vector1)

    # re normalize the vector
    pg_vector = pg_vector1 / pg_vector1_norm

print(pg_vector)
```

HS is as the following:

```
<10001x10001 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 282137 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

pg_vector is as the following with 10001 rows × 1 columns.

```
array([9.9990001e-05, 9.9990001e-05, 9.9990001e-05, ..., 9.9990001e-05,
       9.9990001e-05, 9.9990001e-05])
```

I tried the following codes in jupyter notebook however, the kernel keeps having to be restarted or it just takes too long to run and I am unable to derive any output from it. Would appreciate if anyone could help with this!

Comment: You can't use np.dot with a sparse matrix. Use the matmul operator @ instead.

Comment: @CJR I tried it but it gives me this error: ValueError: matmul: Input operand 0 does not have enough dimensions (has 0, gufunc core with signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) requires 1)

Comment: Your matrices are not shaped in a way that they can be multiplied. You should probably debug that.

Comment: @CJR previously i used matmul(HS, pg_vector) which gave the error. However, after i changed it to HS @ pg_vector , it works now

Comment: Yeah, the numpy functions don't work with scipy sparse arrays. You have to use the operator to get to the scipy `__matmul__` that does work. Just as a warning, it makes a numpy matrix, not an array - it's got some weird behavior compared to arrays.